# Basic Passive Voice. I just can't understand

Tags: passive-voice

I'm preparing for exam. And there's an interesting question for which I don't know the correct answer.

Then the bottles ... into boxes of twenty four.

A) are packed

B) packed

C) will packed

D) are been packed

C is not correct. It should be sth like 'will be packed'. B is not correct because of lack of verb to be. There're 2 options left. Both in Present tense. And I don't know which one should I choose.
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: D is ungrammatical. *BE* can be an auxiliary for  continuous constructions or for the passive. The continuous one is followed by an *-ing* form, the passive one by a past participle. The passive *BE*  always appears last. The auxiliary always determines the form of the verb that comes afterwards. So D) should be *are being packed* in order to be grammatical.

Comment: The answer is A, it is the only correct answer.

Comment: See passive conjugation in: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295015/does-starting-a-sentence-with-it-is-make-it-passive/295018#295018

Answer (score 1):

There is no valid English tense which is {form of *to be*} + {past participle} + {another past participle}.

So *are been packed* is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context of your previous sentences of the overall action preformed. If someone performing packing of the bottles then use D):

> Then the bottles are been packed into boxes of twenty four

**NOTE:** As @WS2 pointed out, this would not make grammatically correct structure. It would be more like this to be grammatically correct:

> The bottles have been packed into boxes of twenty four

...and therefore is not an option to use.

That leaves only one option A:

> Then the bottles are packed into boxes of twenty four

Comment: The first sentence is not grammatical. The only one which produces a grammatical answer is A. *Then the bottles are packed into boxes of 24*.